# multi uom for different product variants

Tags: odoo-15

I'm designing an odoo system for a factory.
The goods are purchased using "kg" as uom, but the sale products will has both kg and mL.
For example:
the package of water can be: 500mL/bottle, 10kg/bucket.
I was thinking use variants for the water product. but the uom of all water variants will be changed if I only wanna change one variant.

what's the best practice in this case? thanks.

Comment: why the uom of all water variants will be changed if you only change one variant?

Comment: because the uom is only based on product level, but not variant.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's just a matter to change the UoM of the product variant at the `sale.order.line` level. That it's something you could definitely can do right now and it's very integrated with packaging and other areas related to the product to be sold.
If you wanna use it on another scenario that it's different than the regular backend Sale Order Workflow you will need to replicate that if that sale it's not ending up to be a `sale.order`, for example `pos.order` will need a minimal tweak in order to allow complete define the line uom, `purchase.order.line` also have the same behavior than `sale.order.line`

If you wanna sale products on the website shop you could extend it to allow the user to select the unit of measure to land on the `sale.order.line`.

If you also wanna support the `product.variant` to have their own UoM you could do it with a custom field but you will need to integrate it with you desired process in order to be used properly.

If you are willing to have this done shortly send me an email with all the details you need and I will quote this work and get it done ASAP